# SaveAs inside BeforeSave (Excel, VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, before-save

I want to program Excel to create back-up of my file before saving it.

But each time I am trying to use it, Excel crashes.

Can please some explain me why this happens even if I insert `Application.EnableEvents = False` to prevent infinite loop?

The code I am using is below:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "BackUp_" & Date & "_" & ActiveWorkbook.Name, FileFormat:=52
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for help!

Comment: I'm not sure if `Date` contains special characters that can not be contained in a file name.

Comment: are you missing a little comma `,` before the `FileFormat:=52` ?

Comment: @ David - Date does not cause problem. Excel crashes even without it.

Comment: @ Shai, thanks for comment, but again problem persists.

Comment: Are opening a workbook on disk or creating new excel file from start menu or , opening it from email or other source besides your disk ?

If the file is not already on disk Activeworkbook.path will not return anything.

Comment: @ Pankaj, file is on my drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I found the reason. `SaveAs` will close the original workbook without saving, and open the new one automatically. Therefore excel can't execute the origin saving script.

Instead, using `SaveCopyAs` could build a copy in background, thus the origin file is still alive in your window.

Try this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "BackUp_" & Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD") & "_" & ActiveWorkbook.Name
End Sub
```

Note: Calling `Date` directly could be like `2017/11/22` which contains `/` ,which is an invalid character, using a `Format` function can prevent an error.

Comment: Thank you for help!
I think I will use your solution)